# PHP getting values from nested json

Tags: php, json

I have this json listed below. I was using json_decode to get some of the values. Such as getting the id value:

```
$decoded_array = json_decode($result, true);
            foreach($decoded_array['issue'] as $issues ){
                    $value[] = $issues["id"];
```

This method is working for getting the id value, however, I want to get the emailAddress values for both Bob and John. I believe you can get a single value by doing this:

```
$value[] = $issues["fields"][people][0][emailAddress];
```

Is it possible to get both email addresses in an efficient manner?

Edited --------

How would you get data with an expanded dataset? Example:

```
{
"startAt": 0,
"issue": [
    {
        "id": "51526",
        "fields": {
            "people": [
                {
                    "name": "bob",
                    "emailAddress": "bob@gmail.com",
                    "displayName": "Bob Smith",
                },
                {
                    "name": "john",
                    "emailAddress": "john@gmail.com",
                    "displayName": "John Smith",
                }
            ],
            "skill": {
                "name": "artist",
                "id": "1"
            }
        }
    },
{
        "id": "2005",
        "fields": {
            "people": [
                {
                    "name": "jake",
                    "emailAddress": "jake@gmail.com",
                    "displayName": "Jake Smith",
                },
                {
                    "name": "frank",
                    "emailAddress": "frank@gmail.com",
                    "displayName": "Frank Smith",
                }
            ],
            "skill": {
                "name": "writer",
                "id": "2"
            }
        }
    }
]

}
```

I only want to extract the email addresses from both "fields". Is there an easy way to loop through all the "fields" to get "emailAddress" data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delve deeper into the array.

```
foreach ($decoded_array['issue'][0]['fields']['people'] as $person) {
  echo $person['emailAddress'];
}
```

Comment: That does it! Thanks for the help